# Hiding element on unusual DOM structure

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem making an element hidden during `:hover`, the problem is the structure of the DOM is hard to navigate, how can I make the `.seperator` hidden when user hovered to `.flex-zero`? If I change the structure I have to make sure the flexbox is working as exactly as it is now, that's the challenge.

```
.selector-wrap {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

    > div {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex: 1;

      &.flex-zero {
        flex: 0;
        visibility: hidden;

        &:hover {
          visibility: visible;

          //here
          how to make seperator hidden?
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/3vp8emc6/

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make the `.seperator` hidden when user hovered to .flex-zero?

With current `DOM structure` its not possible with `css,` of course  possible with `jquery`.

Rather than changing the `DOM structure`  ,You can try this

```
.selector-wrap:hover .seperator {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: @SharonChai Then its better to use  JS